# Analytics reports with User-ID is not accurate

Tags: google-analytics

I implemented on my site the User-ID in Google Analytics to really accurate reports. However, to my surprise, when generating a custom report with my custom dimensions in places that I know that have been accessed by one person analytics shows incorrect values (the value 2 in the example image).
What can I do to fix this?

(more details)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOxgK.png)

I'm already using a view with the configured User-ID, and analytics is receiving data about two weeks this way. I know the information I'm sending is correct since checked with the extension of the chrome "Assistant Tag".

I have some "Custom Dimensions" to separate my users by divisions of sectors used internally in the company.

My problem is that to generate the report based on that "Custom Dimensions" in areas where I know they were only accessed by a single user in the report is presented as 2.

I would like to have a report that shows to me the access number no matter how many times the same user access to the same url it appears in the report as a single user.

Comment: Welcome to SO Augusto. There really is not enough information in your question to make any reliable suggestions. For example if you are querying for information that happened today you might be running into [Data Processing Latency](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983#DataProcessingLatency), but from your question there is not enough information to rule anything out. SO really likes it when you show your code and any error messages you've received. Is it a [User Id](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662) enabled view?

Comment: Thanks Matt!

I updated my question with more information.

Comment: Can you expound on the hits that were sent from this single user? Did they have different [`cid`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid) but the same [`uid`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uid)? How are you generating the `uid`? Is it in accordance with the [TOS](https://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html)? A lot of people use a separate user scoped custom dimension in which the store a copy of the `uid`, have you done this to prove to yourself that both users have the same `uid`?